# Which is the height considered 3 tefachim for not "praying in height"? (30cm?)

Tags: tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, shiurim-measurements, chazzan-prayer-leader

Recently we had to make a synagogue for one day at a hall, and we used a scaffold for the Shaliach tzibbur to be well heard by all the public.

The Scaffold was 1m x 1.5m, and I don't remember the exact height. So I was wondering what would be considered "Makom Gavoha" (3 tefachim), is it 8cm, 10cm or 12cm times 3? (24,30,36 cm respectively)

The Siman on the SH"A is 90. Look Mishna Berura S"K 5.

I think the relative "fear" of the shaliach tzibur is not to take into account, since SH"A does not mention it, and Mishna Berurah bring it in the name of "iesh mehaachaaronim shecatbu", and we follow SH"A Psakim in all matters.

Comment: Hello iair and welcome to J.SE! Maybe it's me but I don't really understand you question. Can you explain a little more? Hope to see you around.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the SH"A does talk about 3 Tefachim, there are different opinions on how long a Tefach is starting at about 8 cm Gra"ch Naeh and up to 9.6 according to the Chason Ish.

According to a psak I read, you need the platform to be at least 4X4 amot (2X2 meters) to get beyond the definition of Makom Gavoha (being that 4X4 amot is considered a **new** place). Also if you put a fence around the Bima (if it is smaller than 2X2 meters). 
This is to allow raising the shaliach tzibur so that the congregation can hear him better - this was accepted in many Kehilot in preference to the original minhag is to put the Chazan **lower** than the people as in "Mimamakim Keraticha"

Hope this helps!
[Source](http://ph.yhb.org.il/02-03-04/)

Comment: That is not representative of the full range of opinions of the length of a tefach

Comment: If you say there are multiple opinions for the length of a tefach,why do you present only one on your length if 4 amot?

Comment: A. Those are the two widely accepted shiurim for tefach, I saw no reason to complicate the matter more than necessary.

Comment: Concerning the ama it is a good question. There is a ratio between the two midot. But I havent seen a discussion of the relevancy of this in connection to the machlokes between grach naeh and chosen ish. This is not to say that there isn't one.